# AngularUI and Multiple jQuery UI Dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm using the jQuery Passthrough module for [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) to separate content into dialogs on my page.  The first dialog works great, the second dialog fails with a "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null."

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wpKa/3/

Comment: With help from the AngularUI devs (thanks folks!), I was able to work-around the issue by wrapping each dialog in its own div:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wpKa/12/

Comment: you should answer your own question and accept it so it's closed

Answer (score 2):

With help from the AngularUI devs (thanks folks!), I was able to work-around the issue by wrapping each dialog in its own div: [jsfiddle.net/3wpKa/12](http://jsfiddle.net/3wpKa/12)

```
<div>
    <div ui-jq="dialog" ui-options="{title: 'Dialog 1', autoOpen: open}">Dialog 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like any wrapping element will help remove this error (I used a `span` in my scenario). Thank you - this information really saved me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Do you have a link to a conversation or some documentation to refer to regarding how this was solved, and what the underlying issue is? This just helped me solve a problem as well, but I'd like to understand what was happening.

Comment: Here's the github issue I filed:  https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/140